# Remove .php extension in .htaccess with already working friendly-url RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried hundreds of answers from this site (questions from other users) but these answers did not worked in my case.

My website is using slugs to display seo-friendly urls and that part is working fine. But I would also like to have some NON dynamic links /static links like this:

`example.com/contact.php` to be displayed/linked without the .php extension, for example `example.com/contact`

But nothings seems to work, and after 12 hours this .htaccess is driving me crazy.

Here is what I have done until now

```
RewriteEngine On

#this is the part for see-friendly urls, this part is working
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-/.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ en.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L] 

#this is the part to remove php extension, this part is NOT working
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**
I am linking the users like this example.com/contact but I get error 404

Comment: "all of them do... not work in my case" - "I noticed that the flag END instead of L loads the pages faster." Wait, does it work or not? Or are you saying that it doesn't work AND it slows down your whole site?

Comment: using friendly urls it works but not the part of removing the .php extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that a rewrite rule doesn't "display a pretty URL", it *reads* the URL sent by the browser, and decides what to do with it. Thinking about "removing the .php from the URL" will put you in the wrong frame of mind.

What you need to be asking is, if the browser sends a URL of "/contact", how should the server decide what page to show - is it "/en.php?slug=contact", or is it "/contact.php"?

The other thing to remember is that *order of rules in the file matters* - if the URL coming in matches the first rule in the file, the server doesn't keep looking down the file for a "better" match. (This is particularly true in this example, since your first rule has the flag "L" for "last"; if that wasn't there, it would be possible for a rule to match the *new* URL, but it still wouldn't be *instead of* the original rule.)

So the solution in this case is simply to change the order of rules in the file: *first* put the section to check if there's a PHP file called "contact.php", and then *only if that rule didn't match* the server will reach the section that says to use "contact" as a slug.

Comment: I edited the question with a better explanation

Comment: @Kamikaza, to be clear, in your HTML you are using links like `<a href="/contact">Contact</a>`, right? That's part of what IMSoP is saying. You have to send traffic to those URLs in the first place, none of the rules posted will change that for you. To have the server "fix" that, you'd also have to add some redirect rules however I personally think it is rarely worth it.

Comment: @Kamikaza I don't see anything in your edit that would change anything I have said in this answer. The side note about the difference between L and END seems to be a completely unrelated question, and should be asked on a separate page if you can't find an existing explanation.

Comment: Yes I am linking users to example.com/contact but I get error 404

Comment: @Kamikaza If there's some part of this answer that you don't understand, please let me know.

Comment: How do I change the order to be correct ? I am very new to htaccess files

Comment: @Kamikaza I just meant to change the order of lines in the file, nothing more complicated than that. Put the part for dealing with ".php" files above the part for dealing with slugs.

Comment: thanks, it worked. But you should maybe put some code in the answer so future users can get help with some code too because not all of them read this small chat

Comment: @Kamikaza On the contrary, I deliberately avoided putting code in the answer, because then people copy and paste it and ignore the explanation that would help them apply it to their own situation. I have edited the answer to make clearer that I'm referring to the order of lines in the file, though.